# SQL Where error in query trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql

*all structure tables in **[sqlfile:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55130)***

*we would like want next query for trigger:*

```
CREATE TRIGGER `INSERT NEW ROW INTO MenuPosition` AFTER INSERT ON `Menu`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO MenuPosition 
SET 
MenuId=NEW.MenuId,
Position = 
(SELECT 1 + IFNULL((SELECT MAX(Position) FROM MenuPosition), 0))
```

*But when we insert row in table `Menu` we get error* `You cann't specify target table 'MenuPosition' for update in FROM clause Update`

Tell me please where my error nd how will be right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very hard to read.  Where did you get the idea of naming a trigger like that?

In any case, your code is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `INSERT NEW ROW INTO MenuPosition`
    AFTER INSERT ON `Menu`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MenuPosition 
        SET MenuId = NEW.MenuId,
            Position = (SELECT 1 + IFNULL((SELECT MAX(Position) FROM MenuPosition), 0))
END
```

Personally, I don't use the `insert . . . set` syntax -- it is not standard.  So, I guess this is a limitation.  The following should work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `INSERT NEW ROW INTO MenuPosition`
    AFTER INSERT ON `Menu`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MenuPosition(MenuID, Position)
        SELECT NEW.MenuId, 1 + IFNULL( (SELECT MAX(Position) FROM MenuPosition), 0)
END
```